# Why does hugging face falcon model use mode.config.use_cache = False, why wouldn't it want to have the decoder re-use computations for fine-tuning?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I was going through the falcon qlora tutorial and I saw this:

```
def get_model_tokenizer_qlora_falcon7b(model_name: str = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16",
                                       config: wand.Config,  # todo
                                       lora_alpha=16,  # todo
                                       lora_dropout=0.1,  # todo
                                       lora_r=64,  # todo
                                       bnb_4bit_compute_dtype = torch.float16,  # changed it from Guanaco hf
                                       ) -> tuple:
    """
    Load the Falcon 7B model, quantize it in 4bit and attach LoRA adapters on it.

    bf16 = 1S, 7Exp, 8Mantissa

    Do:
        pip install bitsandbytes
    ref:
        - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DOi8MFv4SWN9NImVornZ7t6BgmLoPQO-#scrollTo=AjB0WAqFSzlD
    """
    from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer

    # model_id = "tiiuae/falcon-7b"
    # model_name: str = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16"

    # - get bnb config for bit-4 base model (bnb lib for using 4bit qlora quantization techniques by tim dettmers)
    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,  # load (usually huge) base model in 4 bits
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",  # normal float 4 for the (usually huge) base model. introduces error but fixed by ft
        # ref: https://gist.github.com/pacman100/1731b41f7a90a87b457e8c5415ff1c14
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bnb_4bit_compute_dtype,
    )

    # - get falcon 4bit model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        trust_remote_code=True  # allows to execute custom code you download from the uploaded model code you are using
    )
    model.config.use_cache = False  # todo: why?
```

why is it using .use_cache = False? usually .use_cache speeds up computation by re-using prev computations in decoder/causal LMs, so why not use it?

context:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BiQiw31DT7-cDp1-0ySXvvhzqomTdI-o?usp=sharing
- https://gist.github.com/pacman100/1731b41f7a90a87b457e8c5415ff1c14
- https://github.com/LambdaLabsML/examples/blob/main/falcon-llm/ft.py
- this one doesn't use the cache false (?): https://huggingface.co/blog/falcon#fine-tuning-with-peft

---

cross:

- [Why does hugging face falcon model use mode.config.use_cache = False, why wouldn't it want to have the decoder re-use computations for fine-tuning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633335/why-does-hugging-face-falcon-model-use-mode-config-use-cache-false-why-wouldn)
- https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1126679691013664778/1126679691013664778
- https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-does-hugging-face-falcon-model-use-mode-config-use-cache-false-why-wouldnt-it-want-to-have-the-decoder-re-use-computations-for-fine-tuning/45951

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.9.1/main_classes/model.html):

> use_cache – (optional) bool If use_cache is True, past key values are used to speed up decoding if applicable to model. Defaults to True.

When fine-tuning the model, you want to use the updated model params. Using the old (cached) values kinda defeats the purpose of finetuning. Hence, the past (cached) key values are disregarded for the fine-tuned model.

Answer (score 0):

Because KV cache is useless during training(Finetune), It only works for inference.

For a Generative Language model.
For a training iteration, all result are computed parallel with casual mask and teacher-forcing, which means all the key and value for different input token are computed in one time.

For a inference iteration, In fact you need to do forward computing many times with different input.

```
    model = xxx
    tokenizer = xxx
    in_text = "Good"
    in_tokens = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(in_text))
    
    # inference
    token_eos = torch.tensor([xxx]) # line break symbol
    out_token = None
    with torch.no_grad():
        while out_token != token_eos:
            logits, _ = model(in_tokens)
            out_token = torch.argmax(logits[-1, :], dim=0, keepdim=True)
            in_tokens = torch.cat((in_tokens, out_token), 0)
            out_text = tokenizer.decode(in_tokens)
```

So with the KV cache, you can save the key,value cache for previous input and you can input one token each time, which looks like

```
    model = xxx
    tokenizer = xxx
    in_text = "Good"
    in_tokens = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(in_text))
    
    # inference
    token_eos = torch.tensor([xxx]) # line break symbol
    out_token = None
    out_text = in_text

    with torch.no_grad():
      while out_token != token_eos:
        logits, kvcache = model(in_tokens, past_key_values=kvcache) 
        out_token = torch.argmax(logits[-1, :], dim=0, keepdim=True)
        in_tokens = out_token 
        text = tokenizer.decode(in_tokens)
        out_text += text
```

in this way, you can get better speed for inference.

Unless you want to train a transformer architecture based model without teacher-forcing, use_cache is always helpless for the training process. But I have not seen a LM trained without teacher-forcing yet.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I have now:

```
    # this is here to save gpu vram. Likely only needed when using 40b or when oom issues happen ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633335/why-does-hugging-face-falcon-model-use-mode-config-use-cache-false-why-wouldn
    model.config.use_cache = use_cache
```

emphasis on comment:

> this is here to save gpu vram. Likely only needed when using 40b or when oom issues happen ref: [Why does hugging face falcon model use mode.config.use_cache = False, why wouldn't it want to have the decoder re-use computations for fine-tuning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633335/why-does-hugging-face-falcon-model-use-mode-config-use-cache-false-why-wouldn)

---

full code:

```
"""
sfttrainer (likely using peft) best practices:
https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/main/en/sft_trainer#best-practices

Best practices

Pay attention to the following best practices when training a model with that trainer:

- SFTTrainer always pads by default the sequences to the max_seq_length argument of the SFTTrainer. If none is passed, the trainer will retrieve that value from the tokenizer. Some tokenizers do not provide default value, so there is a check to retrieve the minimum between 2048 and that value. Make sure to check it before training.
- For training adapters in 8bit, you might need to tweak the arguments of the prepare_model_for_int8_training method from PEFT, hence we advise users to use prepare_in_int8_kwargs field, or create the PeftModel outside the SFTTrainer and pass it.
- For a more memory-efficient training using adapters, you can load the base model in 8bit, for that simply add load_in_8bit argument when creating the SFTTrainer, or create a base model in 8bit outside the trainer and pass it.
- If you create a model outside the trainer, make sure to not pass to the trainer any additional keyword arguments that are relative to from_pretrained() method.

todo: why trust_remote_code? I want more details.
"""
import torch
from peft import LoraConfig


def test_bfloat16_int4(compute_dtype: torch.dtype,
                       use_4bit,
                       ):
    """
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.get_device_capability());"
    todo: check other code test_bfloat16() do we need use_4bit?
    """
    if compute_dtype == torch.float16 and use_4bit:
        major, _ = torch.cuda.get_device_capability()
        if major >= 8:
            print("=" * 80)
            print("Your GPU supports bfloat16, you can accelerate training with the argument --bfloat16")
            print("=" * 80)


def get_model_tokenizer_qlora_falcon7b(
        # -- mode args
        # model_id = "tiiuae/falcon-7b"
        model_name: str = "ybelkada/falcon-7b-sharded-bf16",
        use_cache: bool = True,
        # -- lora args
        lora_alpha=16,  # todo
        lora_dropout=0.1,  # todo, evidence drop out really help? google, crfm, gpt4
        lora_r=64,  # todo
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,  # changed it from Guanaco hf
        # -- training args
        output_dir="./results",
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        # paging so that the sudden mem gpu spikes don't cause the run to shut down
        # (I think usually caused by too long seqs)
        # todo: why 32 bit opt?
        # todo: paged nadamw opt?
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
        save_steps=10,
        logging_steps=10,
        learning_rate=2e-4,
        max_grad_norm=0.3,
        max_steps=500,
        warmup_ratio=0.03,
        lr_scheduler_type="constant",
        # -- quant. args (not recommended to be changed unless you know what your doing?)
        load_in_4bit=True,  # load (usually huge) base model in 4 bits
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",  # normal float 4 for the (large) base models qlora
) -> tuple:
    """
    Load the Falcon 7B model, quantize it in 4bit and attach LoRA adapters on it.

    bf16 = 1S, 7Exp, 8Mantissa
    hypothesis: 7b trained due to 6.7 emergence rumour, I still don't think emergence is real.
    Notes:
        - ft a model is very specific to the model, tokenizer and training scheme. Thus we return
            - model, tokenizer, ft config (peft config), training args

    ref:
        - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DOi8MFv4SWN9NImVornZ7t6BgmLoPQO-#scrollTo=AjB0WAqFSzlD
    """
    from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer

    # - Get bnb config for bit-4 base model (bnb lib for using 4bit qlora quantization techniques by tim dettmers)
    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=load_in_4bit,  # load (usually huge) base model in 4 bits
        bnb_4bit_quant_type=bnb_4bit_quant_type,  # normal float 4 for the (usually huge) base model
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bnb_4bit_compute_dtype,  # if you can, during computation use bf16
    )

    # - Get falcon 4bit model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        trust_remote_code=True  # allows to execute custom code you download from the uploaded model code you are using
    )
    # this is here to save gpu vram. Likely only needed when using 40b or when oom issues happen ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633335/why-does-hugging-face-falcon-model-use-mode-config-use-cache-false-why-wouldn
    model.config.use_cache = use_cache

    # - Get falcon tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)  # execs code downloaded from hf hub
    # tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token  # todo: why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633368/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token

    # - Get falcon lora config
    peft_config = LoraConfig(
        lora_alpha=lora_alpha,
        lora_dropout=lora_dropout,
        r=lora_r,
        bias="none",
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
        # model card for falcon tiiuae/falcon-7b: https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-7b/blob/main/modelling_RW.py
        # does seem to include all trainable params as done by qlora on their own paper
        target_modules=[
            "query_key_value",
            "dense",
            "dense_h_to_4h",
            "dense_4h_to_h",
        ]
    )

    # todo: print the num params of the lora = D1*r + D2*r and num of bytes by prec. (bytes) * num params

    # Get training args
    from transformers import TrainingArguments

    training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,
        per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
        optim=optim,
        save_steps=save_steps,
        logging_steps=logging_steps,
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        fp16=True,
        max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
        max_steps=max_steps,
        warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
        group_by_length=True,
        lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
    )
    return model, tokenizer, peft_config, training_arguments
```